# Unix separate string line with delimiter

Tags: unix, awk, delimiter

I have a few line of string in txt file like this:

input.txt-->

```
abc;def;ghi jklm;mno pqr;
abcde;fgh;ijk lmno;pqrs tuv;
```

my code is this. It did not work with space. 
Please help.

```
awk -F";" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' input.txt | while read var1    
var2 var3 var4 
Do
 echo 'var1 = ' $var1
 echo 'var2 = ' $var2
 echo 'var3 = ' $var3
 echo 'var4 = ' $var4
Done
```

desired output-->

```
var1 = abc
var2 = def
var3 = ghi jklm
var4 = mno pqr

var1 =abcde
var2 =fgh
var3 =ijk lmno
var4 =pqrs tuv
```

Comment: why are you passing the awk output to a `while read ... do ; ... done ` loop. You can get much sophisticated parsing and printing inside of `awk`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

This can make it:

```
while IFS=';' read -r val1 val2 val3 val4
do
  echo "val1 = $val1"
  echo "val2 = $val2"
  echo "val3 = $val3"
  echo "val4 = $val4"
done < input.txt
```

The basic aspect to take into consideration is `IFS=";"` which defines the Input Field Separator. With `read -r val1 .. val4` we indicate which variables will be defined.

It can be easier with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F";" '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {print "val"i,"=",$i}}' input.txt
```

It basically defines `;` as field separator with the `-F ";"`. Then loops through all these fields with the `for i` and prints them. `NF` indicates the number of fields and The loop is up to `NF-1` so that the last empty one is not shown. [Thanks JS웃  for the tip :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744970/unix-separate-string-line-with-delimiter#comment25871839_17745071)

#### Test

```
$ while IFS=';' read -r val1 val2 val3 val4; do echo "val1 = $val1"; echo "val2 = $val2"; echo "val3 = $val3"; echo "val4 = $val4"; echo; done < a
val1 = abc
val2 = def
val3 = ghi jklm
val4 = mno pqr

val1 = abcde
val2 = fgh
val3 = ijk lmno
val4 = pqrs tuv
```

`awk` version:

```
$ awk -F";" '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {print "val"i,"=",$i}}' a
val1 = abc
val2 = def
val3 = ghi jklm
val4 = mno pqr
val1 = abcde
val2 = fgh
val3 = ijk lmno
val4 = pqrs tuv
```

Comment: Thanks @Kent, I was adapting my test to show the expected variables... and missed some of them :)

Comment: +1 for `awk` version you can do `<NF` instead of `<=NF` to prevent the `if` loop

Comment: Oooh thanks @JS웃! So I answered this question *with a little help from my friends*

Comment: @fedorqui *Dando y dando, pajarito volando*

Comment: Hehe we are such a family in these tags :) @JS웃